# Whatsapp Help for Ubuntu 14.04!

Tags: command-line, scripts, software-installation

Hey i have found a way to use Whatsapp on ubuntu using Pidgin!
But i don't understand everything on the site...
Can someone help me?

I have completed the pidgin installation and whatsapp plugin.
Now i have to do the SMS whatsapp verification.
See the script for that here : http://samtinkers.wordpress.com/2014/01/11/install-whatsapp-on-ubuntu-12-04-12-10-13-04-13-10-mint-13141516/

Can someone tell me how do i exactly do the commands and codes etc.

Thanks,

Comment: execute each line as it says there, don't copy paste everything. read the blog post and then understand what you need to do, I got it quite easily.

Answer (score 1):

For the most cases you should execute the code line by line. The comments (lines starting with a #) are mostly things to fill in a file, you edit with an editor (vi) or terminal output. Sometimes you have to be careful, which lines are just output or additional info and which are commands.

```
sudo apt-get install python python-dateutil python-argparse
sudo wget https://github.com/tgalal/yowsup/archive/master.zip
sudo unzip master.zip
cd yowsup-master/src
cp config.example yowsup-cli.config
vi yowsup-cli.config
```

These lines for example are simple commands that install needed packages and open a config file to edit.

After editing, executing

```
chmod +x yowsup-cli
```

makes the file executable and the following command requests an authorisation code:

```
./yowsup-cli --requestcode sms --config yowsup-cli.config
```

After receiving the code via SMS, you can retrieve another code to identify with Whatsapp:

```
./yowsup-cli --register 123-456 --config yowsup-cli.config
```

(replace 123-456 with the code)

After that

```
cat yowsup-cli.config
```

displays the config file, where (I guess) something like

```
cc=34
phone=34123456789
id=
password=S1nBGCvZhb6TBQrbm2sQCfSLkXM=
```

is standing.

After that you can install the Whatsapp Plugin for Pidgin using

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:whatsapp-purple/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install pidgin-whatsapp
```

and login with your phone number and the authorisation code/password (In the example `S1nBGCvZhb6TBQrbm2sQCfSLkXM=`).

Comment: And after i edited it what do i have to do then?

Comment: I have really much trouble while doing this, can you do me a big favor? please make a video while you doing this?

Comment: I am not using Whatsapp with Ubuntu, I just tried to figure out, what the guide tells you to do. Where exactly are you stuck?

Comment: I am stuck at the editing ....

Comment: I don't know where i can edit it correctly

Comment: Have you executed "vi yowsup-cli.config"?

Comment: I'm really dumb i'm sorry for being dumb but how can i execute something.

Comment: You type the phrase into terminal and press enter.

Comment: Thanks i did that and what do i have to do now??

Comment: Now you can type Edit the file that it matches the lines written in the comment below the command.

Comment: no such folder `yowsup-master/src`

Answer (score 1):

this is sam from the blog,

If you've gotten as far as mentioned in the previous post, 
all you need to do is

open pidgin, go to accounts -> manage accounts -> from the protocol, select whatsapp -> enter your phone number with the country code as username, and the password string from the file as the password -> click on add.

After this, you will have a working whatsapp on your pidgin, however, you will need to add the contacts on your own, using add buddy, and entering their phone numbers.