# How to use pidgin-whatsapp in Ubuntu?

Tags: 12.04

Is it possible to execute Whats app in Ubuntu 12.04?

I executed the command

```
sudo apt-get install pidgin-whatsapp
```

and get the following error message

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package pidgin-whatsapp
```

what is the problem with the command.

Comment: But unable to connect  with pidgin-whatsapp and getting `Server closed the connection error` on pidgin, Is there any other client ?

Answer (score 4):

You need to add its repository before you try to install the plugin.

Execute the following:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:whatsapp-purple/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install pidgin-whatsapp
```

Comment: But unable to connect and getting `Server closed the connection` error on  pidgin, Is there any other client ?

Answer (score 2):

## How To: Use WhatsApp under Ubuntu

There are many ways to get [WhatsApp Messenger](http://www.whatsapp.com/) to work on Ubuntu, some I have tried, such as a native WhatsApp replacement called [WhosThere (Now Discontinued)](https://launchpad.net/whosthere), or via emulator. You can read more about all that here: "[WhatsApp and Viber in Ubuntu 13.04](http://www.eurobytes.nl/tutorials/howto-install-whatsapp-and-viber-in-ubuntu-13.04.php)". But, we will now get WhatsApp to work using [Pidgin, the universal chat client](http://pidgin.im/), with a third party plugin called [whatsapp-purple](https://launchpad.net/~whatsapp-purple/+archive/ubuntu/ppa). Do note that WhatsApp cannot be activated on your Desktop and phone at the same time.

### Yowsup

[Yowsup](https://github.com/tgalal/yowsup/) is - simply put - `A library to use WhatsApp from Python`. Not so simply put:

> Yowsup allows you to login and use the Whatsapp service
>   and provides you with all capabilities of an official Whatsapp client,
>   allowing you to create a full-fledged custom Whatsapp client. - 
>   [About Yowsup, github.com/tgalal/yowsup/](https://github.com/tgalal/yowsup/#about-yowsup)

Yowsup depends on some packages, install them as follows:

```
sudo apt-get install python python-dateutil python-argparse
```

The commands below will download, unpack, and open the Yowsup config file.

```
wget https://github.com/tgalal/yowsup/archive/master.zip
unzip master.zip
cd yowsup-master/src
cp config.example yowsup-cli.config
nano yowsup-cli.config
```

You don't have to use `nano`, use an editor that you are most comfortable with. As you are editing the yowsup config file: `yowsup-cli.config`, find the line `phone=XXXXXXXXXX`, type in you phone number with country code (For example: +31612345678).

When you have done that, we'll have to make the file executable: `chmod +x yowsup-cli`. When we are able to execute the file, we will request an authorization code:

```
./yowsup-cli --requestcode sms --config yowsup-cli.config
```

After you received the code - usually in the following format: "`XXX-XXX`" - we will register it:

```
./yowsup-cli --register XXX-XXX --config yowsup-cli.config
```

It should display the information you need. In my case it displayed it immediately after running the command:

```
./yowsup-cli --register 503-417 --config yowsup-cli.config
Detected cc: 31
status: ok
kind: paid
pw: EDITED OUT
price: € 0,89
price_expiration: EDITED OUT
currency: EUR
cost: 0.89
expiration: 4444444444.0
login: EDITED OUT
type: existing
```

*Don't close that terminal window*. I could not find the outputted information anywhere. Copy the information from the terminal using <kbd>Cntrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd>. Save it somewhere, for example in `yosup.txt`.

### Pidgin

Now, we will install `pidgin`, and the `pidgin-whatsapp` plugin:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:whatsapp-purple/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install pidgin pidgin-whatsapp
```

Select the WhatsApp protocol from the drop down menu:

Your user name is your phone number, with country code, and password is in the file you previously copied and saved. `pw: longpassword`. Copy them both in, click add, then you should get all the groups you're in. Again, remember, this cannot work when you also have it activated on your phone. Either desktop, or phone, but not both at the same time.

[image: Pidgin Account Window]

That was it. Hopefully in the future they will change the infrastructure so that both can be activated at the same time. Or even better, follow in the footsteps of [Viber](http://www.eurobytes.nl/tutorials/native-viber-for-linux), and release a desktop client for Linux.

#### References:

- [askubuntu.com: Whatsapp Help for Ubuntu 14.04! [duplicate]](https://askubuntu.com/a/459016/36315)
- [pidgin.im: Pidgin, the universal chat client](http://pidgin.im/)
- [developer.pidgin.im: ThirdPartyPlugins – Pidgin](https://developer.pidgin.im/wiki/ThirdPartyPlugins)
- [github.com: davidgfnet/whatsapp-purple](https://github.com/davidgfnet/whatsapp-purple)
- [launchpad.net: whatsapp-purple : “whatsapp-purple Packagers” team](https://launchpad.net/~whatsapp-purple/+archive/ubuntu/ppa)

**Source**:

Excerpt from:

- [How To: Use WhatsApp under Ubuntu - EuroBytes](http://www.eurobytes.nl/tutorials/how-to-use-whatsapp-under-ubuntu)

Which I am the author of.

Comment: Doesn't work. First, there's neither `config.example`, nor even `src` dir. But whatever, I found the example [here](http://dnevniki.ykt.ru/%D0%98%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%9F%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9/705288). Second, the command outputs error: `./yowsup-cli --requestcode sms --config config.example` `Available commands:
===================
demos, version, registration`

Comment: Aha, [thanks to this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28000183/2388257) and [this](https://github.com/tgalal/yowsup/wiki/yowsup-cli-2.0), it seems that command line now changed, and the command would look like this `./yowsup-cli registration --requestcode sms --config config.example`. But it still outputs error — this time about an index being out of range. Looking at stacktrace, I'd guess that the config file is wrong. It'd be nice now to find the right one.

Comment: Okay, I figured it out. No need in whatever config file, the right command to get the code is `./yowsup-cli registration --requestcode sms -C YourContryCode -p YourContryCodeThenPhoneNumber`, where YourContryCode to be replaced with the code, and YourContryCodeThenPhoneNumber with the code and following number. E.g. for Russia: `./yowsup-cli registration --requestcode sms -C 7 -p 71234567890`. What's worrying me though is that the code still doesn't come… I guess, API broke — yesterday I tried some site to get the code, and that didn't work either.

Comment: Yay, sms didn't work, but «voice» worked! Just change `sms` to `voice`, they would call you. Note, however, the language is english with disregard to country, so if you don't know it well, you may want to record the call.

Comment: @Hi-Angel @all But unable to connect and getting `Server closed the connection error` on pidgin, Is there any other client ?

Comment: @Nullpointer unfortunately I stopped using it in a few days for irrelevant reasons *(I was registering there because of a girl, but we quarreled)*, so dunno. You may want to report a bug to a project. Also IIRC I found Whatsapp is asking a small fee. However insignificant it is, it's tripping me out because there's a bunch of cross-platform and free alternative messengers, which definitely deserve much better than Whatsapp, wtf. So I concluded usage of Whatsapp just silly.

Answer (score 0):

You can only install whatsapp via an emulator like Bluestacks.

Or check this link: [How To: Use WhatsApp under Ubuntu - EuroBytes](http://www.eurobytes.nl/tutorials/how-to-use-whatsapp-under-ubuntu)

Answer (score 0):

Mine did work. If anyone is still having this issue here is how i did it;

I first navigated to the folder where my yowsup-master is then I run the following command to get the config example,

```
    ./yowsup-cli registration --help-config
```

Then copy the config to your favorite text editor, edit the phone number details, then save the file as yowsup-cli.config, then run the following command;

```
   ./yowsup-cli registration --requestcode sms --config yowsup-cli.config
```

The n they will send you a confirmation code

Answer (score 0):

I use [Franz](http://meetfranz.com/) a free messaging app that combines chat & messaging services into one application.

Franz currently supports Slack, WhatsApp, WeChat, HipChat, Facebook Messenger, Telegram, Google Hangouts, GroupMe, Skype and many more.